# Read whether .NET library is COM registered

Tags: .net, command-line, com-interop, regasm

I have a library that is to be registered for COM Interop:

```
%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\regasm MyTest.dll
%Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\<version>\regasm MyTest.dll
```

Now before doing so, I only want to find out whether the library is already registered for COM Interop, without changing the system configuration. **How can I do so?** Also, I want to find out whether other versions of the same library (newer and older) are already registered for COM Interop.

The official [regasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.110).aspx) manual page does now show any parameter that would only output whether a library is already registered.

Comment: Use the /reg option to see what registry keys you have to check.  Do keep in mind that regasm.exe *not* having this option built-in is very much by design.  You are asking for DLL Hell, sooner or later you are going to regret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the registry programmatically (like any COM server, not only .NET), for example, here is what produces the regasm for a class named `net2.Class1` in an assembly named 'net2.dll", that was registered with the /codebase argument:

[image]

For a non .NET COM Server, the important part is the default value of the `HKCR\CLSID\<your CLSID>\InprocServer32 key` which points to the dll that exposes functions to create the declared COM objects.

For a .NET class, this value must be set to `mscoree.dll` (which is part of all .NET installations), and then what's also important is the keys `Assembly` and `Class`.

Note I have provided an equivalent sample of RegAsm in C# code here: [Registering a COM without Admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782404/registering-a-com-without-admin-rights), you can also use it the other way round to determine what are the important keys.