# How to deploy COM-object with VS2022 installer project?

Tags: .net, com, windows-installer, visual-studio-2022, regasm

For installation I need operation

```
 regasm /codebase X.dll
```

but there are a couple problem, usually nobody understanding folder with regasm and secondary - how to add this command to installer project. Where is the place I need to click for add regasm command?

VS2022 installer project

[image: 1]

Comment: I don't think the installer project (which is an old tool) knows how to do the equivalent or regasm. What you could do is use registration with custom code instead of regasm, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35782404/registering-a-com-without-admin-rights

Comment: @SimonMourier. Interesting, thank you. But I need MSI installer for my end user. So, I need compile code from your reference as EXE, it's possible of course. But additionally I need to start this util during installatation, isn't it? I never adding custom script to installer project so far. Where is place to add custom script to installer project - this is last question in this case.